# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythomnic3k

Good Afternoon,

1. I am using pythomnic3k python framework and sharded solr, redis database servers.

   Following is my api request:

   `http://1.2.3.4:8090/api20/account2/addnewemail?Email=foo@yahoo.com&Token=[redacted]&AccountID=[redacted]`

   error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`
2. Function where this error arises:

   ```
   def count_maps(r):
       dt = r.get(Namespace.MAPPINGS + ':count')
   ```

   r is redis instance and `Namespance.Mappings + ':count' = ytk:map:count`
3. solr schema xml file has these sharded instance:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <mapping>
           <meta>
               <date>201-12-13 00:00:00</date>
               <active>true</active>
               <static url="0.0.0.0:8983/solr" />
           </meta>
           <map>
               <shard url="0.0.0.0:8983/solr" start="00000000" end="00009999" readonly="false">
                   <slave url="0.0.0.0:8983/solr" />
               </shard>
           </map>
       </mapping>
   ```

1. Redis instance r is in redis_utils.py

   ```
   def test_redis_obj(r):
   try:
       r.ping()
       return True
   except ConnectionError: 
       return False

   def redis_obj(redis_def, timeout = None):
   if not redis_def:
       return None
           return redis.StrictRedis(
               host = redis_def["ip"],
               port = redis_def["port"],
               db = redis_def["db"],
               socket_timeout = timeout
           )

   def random_redis_obj(timeout = None):
       return redis_obj(random_redis_def(), timeout)

   def random_tested_redis_obj(attempts = 3, timeout = 1):
       for _ in range(attempts):
           r = random_redis_obj(timeout)
           if r and test_redis_obj(r):
               return r
   raise YtkRedisError("active redis server not found (%d attempts done)" % attempts)
   ```
2. Here is function where `count_maps(r)` is called in solr_manager.py:

   ```
   def get_unique_shards(r, the_map: int = -1):
       '''
       Returns array: [map][shard](0: url; 1: [slaves urls])
       with unique shards with their slaves in mappings
       '''
   num = count_maps(r)
   if the_map >= num:
       raise IndexError("There aren't map at index " + str(the_map))
   if the_map < 0:
       return _get_all_unique_shards(r, num)
   else:
       return _get_unique_shards(r, the_map)

   def count_maps(r):
       dt = r.get(Namespace.MAPPING + ':count')
       if dt is not None:
           return int(dt)
       return None
   ```

   - I understand this redis object try to count solr instances, is it right ?
   - Kindly help me in what can be possible reason why my redis object is None ? I checked my logs same 'get attribute..' error and unable to debug it.

Comment: `r` is not `None`; according to your error, it is a function. Please post the code where you create `r`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated my question with code where r is declared,

Comment: No you haven't: you've posted some code which returns an object called `r`. Which doesn't call `count_maps`. BTW - Is this really your whitespace?

Comment: @doctorlove sorry if it is still not clear, but I am trying to put all information I understand.

Comment: Well, now you're calling `get_unique_shards()` with an argument `r`. Which you still don't show the creation of. And where's the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

As I got your question, an `r` is a connection to `redis`, if it's so you can define at the beggining of your `py` file like:

```
import redis

r = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

Than you can use `r` as:

```
def count_maps():
    dt = r.get(Namespace.MAPPING + ':count')
    if dt is not None:
        return int(dt)
    return None
```

Comment: thanks, but I am using `from shared.redis_utils import decode_obj, random_tested_redis_obj` at the very top of the file. You are right but `r` is `StrictRedis` not using connection pool, thanks I think I am close after your answer